# How to traverse for duplicates and create mappings in python

Tags: python, traversal

I have a dictionary with values as below

```
test_dict = {"key" : {"Apple", "Appl", "phone", "case", "APPLE"}}
```

Using fuzzy matching will find whether two strings are equal similar to below. Expected output is to create a map of duplicates in a single group keeping the first comparing duplicate as a key. What is the best way to get to this solution.

```
for k, value in test_dict.items():
    for val in values: 
        if fuzzy_score(val[0], val[1]) > 95:
            final_dict[val[0]].append(val[1])
            values.remove(val[1]) # Remove since we already found val[1] is a duplicte of val[1]
        if fuzzy_score(val[0], val[2]) > 95:
            final_dict[val[0]].append(val[2])
            values.remove(val[2]) # Remove since we already found val[1] is a duplicte of 
        ......
```

Excepted output:

```
>> print(final_dict)
"Apple" : {"Appl", "APPLE"}
```

Comment: Do you have a solution that is not the best way? What is the problem with it?

Comment: I was more stuck with writing the more optimal recursive functions which would work for larger lists

Comment: does your real data look like `test_dict = {"key" : {"Apple", "Appl" ... }}`?
everything is in single dict key ?
Input data is provided by you? Can you change the initial structure?

Comment: @luvatar, Yes it would be single dictionary for now and the input is provided by me.

Comment: There is this data structure `trie tree`.  
If you normalize words(lower case) it should be perfect for these values. Not sure about performance but it would group data in similar sets